# Inquiry about ResourceBundle in java

Tags: java, io, resourcebundle

Directly from this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29):

> Otherwise, getBundle attempts to locate a property resource file using
>   the generated properties file name. It generates a path name from the
>   candidate bundle name by replacing all "." characters with "/" and
>   appending the string ".properties". It attempts to find a "resource"
>   with this name using ClassLoader.getResource.

What do they mean with `replacing all "." characters with "/"` What would be an example?
PS:I am ok with appending .properties at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a package named

```
com.yourgroup.bundles
```

containing a file named

```
hello_en_US.properties
```

you would have to specify either of the following to load a bundle

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.yourgroup.bundles.hello");
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/yourgroup/bundles/hello");
```

Basically the javadoc is telling you how it translates the argument you pass to the `getBundle` method to find the resource on your classpath. For me, the default Locale is `en_US`, so

```
com.yourgroup.bundles.hello
```

translates to

```
com/yourgroup/bundles/hello_en_US.properties
```

It can then use the `ClassLoader` to find that resource.

The `ResourceBundle` implementation it returns might actually be a custom class, if you map its name correctly. Follow the javadoc for that. Otherwise, it's just a `Properties` resource bundle.

The magic happens in `ResourceBundle#newBundle(...)`

```
String bundleName = toBundleName(baseName, locale); // baseName being 'com.yourgroup.bundles.hello' in my example above
...
final String resourceName = toResourceName(bundleName, "properties");
```

and that is simply

```
public final String toResourceName(String bundleName, String suffix) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bundleName.length() + 1 + suffix.length());
    sb.append(bundleName.replace('.', '/')).append('.').append(suffix);
    return sb.toString();
}

....

URL url = classLoader.getResource(resourceName);
...
bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(stream); // stream comes from url
```